# Trail Renderer Collision detection of painted Line

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity, I want to paint a shape (any object shape) on the screen by mouse and when drawn lines collide I want to find collision detection on it and fill the area of line collision with color.

The Code is referenced from "http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/draw-line-mouse-move-detect-line-collision-unity2d-unity3d".

So far, here is my code:

```c#
private LineRenderer line;
private bool isMousePressed;
public List<Vector3> pointsList;
private Vector3 mousePos;

// Structure for line points
struct myLine
{
    public Vector3 StartPoint;
    public Vector3 EndPoint;
};
//    -----------------------------------    
void Awake ()
{
    // Create line renderer component and set its property
    line = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer> ();
    line.material = new Material (Shader.Find ("Particles/Additive"));
    line.SetVertexCount (0);
    line.SetWidth (0.1f, 0.1f);
    line.SetColors (Color.green, Color.green);
    line.useWorldSpace = true;    
    isMousePressed = false;
    pointsList = new List<Vector3> ();
    //        renderer.material.SetTextureOffset(
}
//    -----------------------------------    
void Update ()
{
    // If mouse button down, remove old line and set its color to green
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        isMousePressed = true;
        line.SetVertexCount (0);
        pointsList.RemoveRange (0, pointsList.Count);
        line.SetColors (Color.green, Color.green);
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {
        isMousePressed = false;
    }
    // Drawing line when mouse is moving(presses)
    if (isMousePressed) {
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
        mousePos.z = 0;
        if (!pointsList.Contains (mousePos)) {
            pointsList.Add (mousePos);
            line.SetVertexCount (pointsList.Count);
            line.SetPosition (pointsList.Count - 1, (Vector3)pointsList [pointsList.Count - 1]);
            if (isLineCollide ()) {
                isMousePressed = false;
                line.SetColors (Color.red, Color.red);
            }
        }
    }
}
//    -----------------------------------    
//  Following method checks is currentLine(line drawn by last two points) collided with line 
//    -----------------------------------    
private bool isLineCollide ()
{
    if (pointsList.Count < 2)
        return false;
    int TotalLines = pointsList.Count - 1;
    myLine[] lines = new myLine[TotalLines];
    if (TotalLines > 1) {
        for (int i=0; i<TotalLines; i++) {
            lines [i].StartPoint = (Vector3)pointsList [i];
            lines [i].EndPoint = (Vector3)pointsList [i + 1];
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<TotalLines-1; i++) {
        myLine currentLine;
        currentLine.StartPoint = (Vector3)pointsList [pointsList.Count - 2];
        currentLine.EndPoint = (Vector3)pointsList [pointsList.Count - 1];
        if (isLinesIntersect (lines [i], currentLine)) 
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
//    -----------------------------------    
//    Following method checks whether given two points are same or not
//    -----------------------------------    
private bool checkPoints (Vector3 pointA, Vector3 pointB)
{
    return (pointA.x == pointB.x && pointA.y == pointB.y);
}
//    -----------------------------------    
//    Following method checks whether given two line intersect or not
//    -----------------------------------    
private bool isLinesIntersect (myLine L1, myLine L2)
{
    if (checkPoints (L1.StartPoint, L2.StartPoint) ||
        checkPoints (L1.StartPoint, L2.EndPoint) ||
        checkPoints (L1.EndPoint, L2.StartPoint) ||
        checkPoints (L1.EndPoint, L2.EndPoint))
        return false;

    return((Mathf.Max (L1.StartPoint.x, L1.EndPoint.x) >= Mathf.Min (L2.StartPoint.x, L2.EndPoint.x)) &&
        (Mathf.Max (L2.StartPoint.x, L2.EndPoint.x) >= Mathf.Min (L1.StartPoint.x, L1.EndPoint.x)) &&
        (Mathf.Max (L1.StartPoint.y, L1.EndPoint.y) >= Mathf.Min (L2.StartPoint.y, L2.EndPoint.y)) &&
        (Mathf.Max (L2.StartPoint.y, L2.EndPoint.y) >= Mathf.Min (L1.StartPoint.y, L1.EndPoint.y)) 
        );
}
```

Comment: Well, you've got a long way to go!

Comment: any ideas you can suggest ?

Comment: What have you tried? Is that how far you've got? Have you not got any ideas of your own?

Comment: Well back in the day i've had a similar problem. I was making a tron like game where i needed collision on trail renderer. What i've done was; i created bunch of empty gameObjects with box collider attached to them and instantiated that empty gameObject along with the trail renderer. Like dozens of empty gameObjects. And i've destoryed them when trail renderer ends. ex 5 seconds. With that tecnique i was able to destroy other gameObjects colliding with trail renderer (They were colliding with empty gameObjecs with collider). Not the best approach maybe but it worked.

Comment: I tried it, it works, but seems a bit not efficient method !

Comment: Yes, that was the best one that i could come up with. If you find a better one let me know please

Comment: Thalthanas, here I found solution which works as expected